# How do you get the current time of day?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do you get the current time (not date AND time)?

Example: 5:42:12 PM

Answer (score 436):

`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` gives it to you as a `TimeSpan` (from midnight).

`DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")` gives it to you as a *string*.

DateTime reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() does the same as the second suggestion.

Comment: well, almost the same, it returns a string but is missing the seconds portion of the time.

Comment: .ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") would give you 17:42:12 PM, while .ToString("h:mm:ss tt") gives you 5:42:12 PM.

Comment: @Kyle - not quite accurate. ToShortTimeString returns the time in the user's selected short time format, as specified in the region settings of Windows.

Answer (score 62):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

For other formats, you can check this site: [C# DateTime Format](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

Answer (score 47):

Another option using String.Format()

```
string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 28):

Current time with AM/PM designator:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Current time using 0-23 hour notation:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: After reading the question again, I think you are not wrong. But I am not wrong either because if this is a general question as you propose, then most of the answerers have misunderstood the question since their answers are not general but specific. All in all, I think the question could have been much clearer. By the way, what does "I undid your -1's" mean?

Comment: Had there not be any misundestandings they would have put all versions not _something_ that comes first on mind. We all know that SO is very generous to people who try hard to answer. But yeah, let's not deviate from the topic much. All I can say is that I will review all my -1's and decide again.

Answer (score 25):

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

Answer (score 18):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt");
```

just Try It's use full to your Need

Answer (score 17):

Here we go:

```
 DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
```

Comment: The `t` in time should be capitalized. Fixed it for your.

Answer (score 14):

This will be better, Try This one

```
    DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

For this you don't need to specify the Format for the Time.

Answer (score 13):

`Datetime.TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan` and might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Get the current date and time, then just use the time portion of it.  Look at the possibilities for formatting a date time string in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

I think this code will solve your problem

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: The `ToString` method has already been covered by several other solutions. In addition, this also does not capture seconds or AM/PM time.

Answer (score 6):

This can be a possible solution:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string time = now.ToString("T");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var CurDate= DateTime.Now;
CurDate.Hour;
CurDate.Minute;
CurDate.Millisecond
```

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the current datetime:

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

string custom = theDate.ToString("d");

MessageBox.Show(custom);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MyEmail.Body = string.Format("The validation is done at {0:HH:mm:ss} Hrs.",DateTime.Now);
```

Can Use `{0:HH:mm:ss}`, `{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}`, `{0:DD/mm/yyy HH:mm:ss}`, etc...

Answer (score 3):

I'm experimenting with this also and find these pages helpful as well.
First the main class...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Now some specifier formats for the ToString method...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
using System;

namespace JD
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DateTime get_UTCNow()
        {
            DateTime UTCNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
            int year = UTCNow.Year;
            int month = UTCNow.Month;
            int day = UTCNow.Day;
            int hour = UTCNow.Hour;
            int min = UTCNow.Minute;
            int sec = UTCNow.Second;
            DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
            return datetime;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime datetime = get_UTCNow();            

            string time_UTC = datetime.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(time_UTC);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

I threw that TimeOfDay method in there just to show that you get a default of 24 hour time as is stated "the time from midnight"

You may use my geter method(); :-D

Answer (score 2):

This will show you only the current time, in 24 hour format:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString().ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Regards
K

Comment: no need to use `ToString()` on `string`s :D

Answer (score 2):

very simple `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: How does this differ from the highest voted answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used the below code to get time alone from DateTime.

```
var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now; 
var currentTimeAlone = new TimeSpan(currentDateTime.Hour, currentDateTime.Minute,    currentDateTime.Second); 
Console.WriteLine(currentTimeAlone);
```

Hope it helps for someone. :)

Answer (score -7):

Try this one. Its working for me in 3tier Architecture Web Application.

```
"'" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "'"
```

Please remember the Single Quotes in the insert Query.

For example:

```
string Command = @"Insert Into CONFIG_USERS(smallint_empID,smallint_userID,str_username,str_pwd,str_secquestion,str_secanswer,tinyint_roleID,str_phone,str_email,Dt_createdOn,Dt_modifiedOn) values ("
 + u.Employees + ","
 + u.UserID + ",'"
 + u.Username + "','"
 + u.GetPassword() + "','"
 + u.SecQ + "','"
 + u.SecA + "',"
 + u.RoleID + ",'"
 + u.Phone + "','"
 + u.Email + "','"
 + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','"
 + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')";
```

The `DateTime` insertion at the end of the line.