# how to get AM/PM from datetime? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a date like this:

```
equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.Date = `{12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM}`
```

and I want to apply time like this, but I do not know how to get AM and PM from the end.

```
dtStartTimeHour.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.TimeOfDay.Hours;
dtStartTimeMin.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.TimeOfDay.Minutes;
**dtStartTimeAMPM.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.???????.;**
```

Please help me.

I have tried something like this:

```
var startDatestr = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.TimeFrom.Split(new string[] { ":", ":",":",":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

AM/PM = startDatestr[3]
```

Comment: If the hours are less than 12, I guess it would be AM, otherwise PM.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875259/how-get-a-m-p-m-from-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the AM/PM value from a DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875259/how-do-i-get-the-am-pm-value-from-a-datetime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the string you can do:

```
equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.ToString("tt");
```

Or for a boolean result use:

```
bool isPM = (equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.Hour >= 12);
```

BTW, you don't need to call `TimeOfDay` - you can get the `Hour` and `Minute` property directly from the `DateTime`:

```
dtStartTimeHour.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.Hour;
dtStartTimeMin.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.Minute;
dtStartTimeAMPM.SelectedItem = equipBooking.BookedFromDteTme.ToString("tt");
```

Comment: @vb1 - 1) no it won't and 2) why is that a problem?

Answer (score 3):

`TimeSpan` does not store time-of-day, but rather the length of any interval of time.   It has no notion of AM/PM.

`TimeOfDay` returns the amount of time since midnight.

If `Hours` is more than or equal to 12, that will be PM.

Answer (score 2):

try using `dateTime.ToString("tt");`