# C# System.DateTime.Now returns customized time format set in windows

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

C# System.DateTime.Now gives me date with time , but it gives me format whatever i have set in windows calander i.e (a.m.)(p.m.) or even (xyz), how to get standard time format (AM/PM) regardless of customized time format set in windows calander?

Comment: DateTime is just that, its doesnt have "format" specifically - if you want it to show in a format you are doing something with it...

Comment: The way the date is represented has nothing to do with its value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7875351/2490247

Comment: If you want a standard format, create an extension method for `DateTime` objects that uses the ToString() method and supply your own format. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) shows the characters used for formatting.

Comment: @To_ALLtry to change windows time AM/PM format to custom values like xyz, then check with System.DateTime.Now... it will give you mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss xyz –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the DateTime as DateTime type then it will automatically show you the format of your windows. For the custom format, you have to cast it as string

```
string newdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

useful link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: rehman your solution works fine as it shows me proper AM.PM format while geting DateTime (isrespective of i have set as xyz instead of AM, or abc instead of PM).     but CultureInfo.InvarinatCuture is independent of culture values? or somewhere it can collide with cuiltural specified formats?

Comment: The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region, take a look at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i have read that article, just wanted to ask your experience with CultureInfo thing, thanks though

Comment: in my experience yes its culture independent and very flexible for variant culture use, in many of my project I have successfully implemented this and outcome is awesome

Comment: I have one little problem, if I even assign DateTime Custure.Invariant value to DataTable column of DateTime , then I get the value of that column in culture specific format?    is there not any way datetime column in datatable should store my culture.invariant value?

Comment: yes it is in invarient culture but when you are displaying data from your pc then it always show as your culture, if you see from other culture then it will show using that culture, it not problem for storing date time, its natural and ok

Comment: thanks Mostafizur, got the same response from jon skeet aswell

Answer (score 3):

`System.DateTime.Now` doesn't have any presentational format, it's the `ToString()` that formats it.

Like:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd, MM");
```

check msdn for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: try to change windows time AM/PM format to custom values like xyz, then check with System.DateTime.Now... it will give you mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss xyz