# Convert Java Date to DateTime not work in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have the Date and Time like this `2016/11/28` and time `07:30 PM`. And combine this string and make like below

```
string mydate = extras.GetString("Apodate") + " " + extras.GetString("Apostarttime");
```

so `mydate` string contain `2016/11/28 07:30PM`.

No I want to convert this string to below format

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

So I try this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
try
{
    Java.Util.Date startdate = dateFormat.Parse(mydate);
    Java.Util.Date enddate = dateFormat.Parse(mydate1);
    SimpleDateFormat rformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(rformat.Format(startdate).ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    model.StartTime = dt1;
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.PrintStackTrace();
}
```

But my `model.StartTime` contain `12/11/0195 7:30:00 PM`. But I want

`2016/11/28 7:30:00 PM`. as a DateTime.

Comment: What `Type` is `model`?

Comment: @Dominik Herold the `model` is my class that i want to post it so I gathering the value and add it to the `model`.

Answer (score 0):

First the thing you should consider to do is
   1. Convert String(type) To DateTime(type)
      - Search how parseExact do first, I think "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" is not the correct datetime format
   2. When you got Datetime(type) you can display to any string format you want
      - Search how to convert type DateTime to string

Link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp#_=_)
  [How do I get the AM/PM value from a DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875259/how-do-i-get-the-am-pm-value-from-a-datetime)

**TLDR;**

```
 SimpleDateFormat rformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");//Format text as what ParseExact method can do 
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(rformat.Format(startdate).ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//plz become Datetime!!! And don't give me a runtime error here
 model.StartTime = dt1;
```

And when you want to display model.StartTime

```
 string Datetxt = model.StartTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm tt'Z'", CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture) //now become a beautiful string with unwanted chars 'T' and  'Z'
```

[image: Result]