# Add hours to local time in Label

Tags: vb.net

It's a simple clock

My `Timer1_Tick` get that code:

```
LocalTime.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```

How to add 6 hours to it?
Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a tutorial site; you are expected to show some effort on your own problem(s).

Comment: I did. But any answer from format TimeOfDay

Answer (score 3):

You should not use labels and textboxes to store your data (a time in this case). Labels should only be used to display some information and textboxes to display and enter information. Store your data in variables, fields and properties.

Define this field in the form

```
Dim t As Date = Date.Now
```

In the method

```
t = t.AddHours(6)
LocalTime.Text = t.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```

I.e. you always work with the value stored in the field and then update the label text from it.

Since the time in the label is stored as a string, you cannot add hours easily. You would have to convert it back to a Date structure, add the hours and then convert it back to a string.

---

If you want to display several clocks in the Timer_Tick you can do  this (note that `Date` in VB is just an alias for the [System.DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) structure):

```
Dim local = DateTime.Now
LocalTime.Text = local.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
AnotherLabel.Text = local.AddHours(6).ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
YetAnotherLabel.Text = local.AddHours(-2).ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: can i use several clocks? how for 2 labels clocks? I want to create world clock in different labels

Comment: Olivier, i can't have AM or PM... PARIS.Text = local.AddHours(2).ToString("HH:mm tt")

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.TimeOfDay` is a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Thus, you could use `Hours` property or `Add` method to change the value. For example:

```
LocalTime.Text = TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(6)).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
```

To subtract hours use [Subtract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `Add`. Also, the same result could be obtained by using `Add` method with negative TimeSpan values:

```
LocalTime.Text = TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(-6)).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
```

**Note**, a `TimeSpan`represents a *time interval*. Let, there is value of elapsed time that is equal to 56 hours 36 minutes and 12 seconds. The AM/PM mark isn't actual for this value. Thus, to get AM/PM time format you need to use values of [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) structure instead of `TimeSpan`:

```
NEWYORK.Text = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(6)).ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

See details in the [Choosing between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) article.

Comment: to substract i have to put - Sub ?

Comment: Thank you Olivier, but the code of Alexander is quite easy and simple for my level :-)
Also, i can't substract hours and get AM or PM with that code why?
   
LocalTime.Text = TimeOfDay

ActualDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("ddd MM yyyy")

NEWYORK.Text = TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(6)).ToString("hh\:mm tt")

LOSANGELES.Text = TimeOfDay.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(9)).ToString("hh\:mm")'

Comment: @Aurel_VB , to substract use negative timespan value. In your case use `-TimeSpan.FromHours(6)` or `TimeSpan.FromHours(-6)`

Comment: @Aurel_VB , `TimeSpan` represents a **time interval**. This could be greater than 24 hours. Thus, to use AM/PM time format  you need to use values of [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) structure instead of `TimeSpan`, for example: `NEWYORK.Text = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(6)).ToString("hh:mm tt")`.

Comment: thank you but i don't know why, AM PM does not appear... :-o I'm getting nervous to do not understand why it doesn't work... :-\ I am using DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: @Aurel_VB , the [`tt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier) format specifier sould help you.

Comment: i am so sorry about that but - tt - don't want show...

PARIS.Text = local.AddHours(2).ToString("HH:mm tt")

Comment: Got it! My windows system set in France of course, so couldn't see it :-)

Comment: @Aurel_VB , you could use `InvariantCulture` option to ignore system localization settings (see [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875351/7914637) for details).

Comment: How to use it? Just before form declaration?

Comment: @Aurel_VB , there's second argument of `ToString` method: `.ToString("hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`