# Join date and time as datetime format and pass it in schedule trigger powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have below date and time in 2 separate variable. I am trying to combine these 2 as date time and create a scheduler based on that but getting error

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:2 char:1
+ $dt1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($dt, 'g',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCultur ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Below is my code

```
$L_Friday="25/02/2022"
$dt = $L_Friday + " " + "10:00:00 AM"
$dt1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($dt, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

```
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ""
```

Please need your help to get the issue here

Comment: Change `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'` to `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'` (`tt` describes `AM/PM`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be like this:

```
$L_Friday="25/02/2022"
$dt = $L_Friday + " " + "10:00:00 AM"
$dt1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($dt, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt' [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
echo $dt1
```

For more details, you can check [this StackOverflow Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875259/how-do-i-get-the-am-pm-value-from-a-datetime).