# How can I get the current time in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to get the current time in C# but when I create a DateTime object, the time is set to 00:00:00.

How can I get the current instance of time?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296920/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-of-day

Comment: 'DateTime itself is a datastructure to work with dates and times. 'DateTime.Now returns the current time.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

this gives it to you as a string.

Comment: For date and time use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 7):

[DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) is what you're searching for...

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString().ToString()
```

This Will give you *DateTime* as `10:50PM`

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
 string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
```

for further details you can check it out : [How do you get the current time of day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296920/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-of-day)