# Read the Windows clock?

Tags: c#, time

I'm making a an alarm clock using a form and making it all pretty with buttons and stuff but I need a way to read the Windows system clock but I am unaware of how to do so. I have read through a few questions here but I am unable to find what I need. I only need to second precision; I'm doing an hour, minutes and second digital clock.

I've read about using the SNTP server like time.windows.com but I don't have that much experience in C# so anything minimal to help me expand my knowledge on C# would be really useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the current time of day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296920/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-of-day), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374089/how-can-i-get-the-current-time-in-c

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Is `DateTime.Now` sufficient for you ? It returns the system time. On modern windows, it will generally (but not always) be setup to be synchronized with a time server at regular intervals.

Comment: Yes, just like the comment below, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The generally accepted way to get the current time is to read the `DateTime.Now` property. This will return a `DateTime` representing the current system time. You can then access the components of that time using the `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second` properties exposed by `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I know it didn't take much but this really helped, thanks. :-)